# How to replace the icons with text on tab?

Tags: android, android-fragments

How to replace the icons with text on tab?  I want to use only text with different fonts.
Please help me .

Comment: whats your point about "tab"?

Comment: Which tab are you addressing? your question isn't clear. please give farther explanation or screenshot

Comment: 'm using sherlock fragments. I want to customize the text on tab using typeface.

Answer (score 1):

Are you mentioning icons on ActionBar??? Please clear.

Because if that is the case

Change your Manifest

```
<application
android:icon="@drawable/launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:name=//your Package name
android:theme="@style/Theme">...
</Application>
```

And in Styles.xml you can use..

```
<style name="Theme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
<item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar</item>
</style>
<style name="ActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
<item name="android:icon">@drawable/icon</item>
</style>
```

In Application icon You can use
Whatever Resource you want even a text

```
<item name="android:icon">//Resuorce You wanna use</item>
```

Comment: S dude am using icons on action bar.

Comment: So can you able to put the text as I haven't tried it personally.